# How to get value of key from the array in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created static array as following below

```
country["0"]=[USA];

sate[country[0][0]]=[["NewYork","NY"],["Ohio,"Oh"]]

for (var i = 0; i < sate[country[0][0]].length; i++) {
    var key = state[country[0][0]] [i][0];
    var value = state[country[0][0]] [i][i+1];
}
```

from above loop i am able to get the keys of state like NewYork and Ohio.
Please help me how i will get the value of "NY" and "Oh"?

Comment: I imagine it's just a typo, but `["Ohio,"Oh"]` is missing a `"` after Ohio.

Comment: That's one ugly array

Comment: I would advice to use objects instead of arrays. With an array it will get messy (assuming there will be more states included in that same array). See: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: Also, sometimes you type `sate` and others `state`.  Wouldn't it be easier to use an object?

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = state[country[0][0]] [i][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple or three errors in your code. Assuming `country` has a list of countries and `state` keeps the states of the country...

```
country = ["USA"];
state = {"USA": [["NewYork","NY"],["Ohio","Oh"]] };

for (var i = 0; i < state[country[0]].length; i++) {
    var key = state[country[0]] [i][0];
    var value = state[country[0]] [i][1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mistyped here

```
sate[country[0][0]]=[["NewYork","NY"],["Ohio", "Oh"]]
```

and You can get ["NY", "Oh"] by using this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sate[country[0][0]].length; i++) {
    var key = state[country[0][0]] [i][0];
    var value = state[country[0][0]] [i][1];
}
```